# Are there practical use cases for one PCIe Physical Function (PF) maps to hundreds or even thousands of Virtual Functions (VF)?

Tags: pci-e

It's known that a single PF can map to multiple VFs.

About the number of VFs associated with a single PF:

- In PCIe 5.0 spec:

  > IMPLEMENTATION NOTE
  >
  > VFs Spanning Multiple Bus Numbers
  >
  > As an example, consider an SR-IOV Device that supports a single PF. Initially, only PF 0 is visible. Software Sets ARI Capable Hierarchy. From the SR-IOV Extended Capability it determines: InitialVFs is 600, First VF Offset is 1 and VF Stride is 1.
  >
  > - If software sets NumVFs in the range [0 … 255], then the Device uses a single Bus Number.
  > - If software sets NumVFs in the range [256 … 511], then the Device uses two Bus Numbers.
  > - If software sets NumVFs in the range [512 … 600], then the Device uses three Bus Numbers.
  >
  > PF 0 and VF 0,1 through VF 0,255 are always on the first (captured) Bus Number. VF 0,256 through VF 0,511 are always on the second Bus Number (captured Bus Number plus 1). VF 0,512 through VF 0,600 are always on the third Bus Number (captured Bus Number plus 2).
- From [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37707_01/html/E29665/usingsriov.html):

  > Each SR-IOV device can have a physical function and each physical function can have up to 64,000 virtual functions associated with it.

From the "sharing PCIe I/O bandwidth" point of view, it might be understandable to having hundres or thousands of VFs (associated with a single PF), each VF is assigned to a VM, with the assumption that most of the VFs are in idle state at a particular time point;

However, from the "chip manufacturing" point of view, for a non-trival PCIe function, duplicating hundreds or thousands of the VF part of the IP instances within a single die would make the die area too large to be practical.

So my question is, as stated in the subject line, are there practical use cases for having so many VFs associcated with a single PF?

Comment: I believe that NICs do. (Network Interface Controller). They have a lot of buffer space for incoming data, so I don't think the space for the VFs is prohibitive in comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @prl. I don't know too much about NIC details but I was assuming that besides buffers a VF also need some extra physical logic to handle packets... I have two NICs both supporting SR-IOV. One is `Mellanox  MT27800 Family [ConnectX-5]`, which has two PFs and each PF support 8 VFs; the other is `Intel 10G X550T`, which has two PFs eaching supporting 32 VFs (it shows it support 64, but I only get 32 VFs so far). Although these two NICs are not high-end ones, I am wondering whether there are commecial NICs supporting say 1K or 4K VFs? Just out of curiosity.